# How to increase heap memory of elasticsearch in Centos 7?

Tags: elasticsearch, centos7, heap-memory, broken-pipe

When we run elasticsearch in server then we face Broken pipe issue in elasticsearch.

"org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe"

Answer (score 0):

We just increase the heap memory of the elasticsearch as given step.

- First check current heap memory of elasticsearch.

  ps aux | grep elasticsearch

  "-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
- Increase the size of heap Memory

  vi /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch

  **Heap size defaults to 256m min, 1g max

  Set ES_HEAP_SIZE to 50% of available RAM, but no more than 31g**

  ES_HEAP_SIZE=3g
- Check new heap memory

  ps aux | grep elasticsearch

  "-Xms3g -Xmx3g"